# use memcpy to fill a struct taking data from an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, memcpy

The following task is from an exam I took in engineering school (mechanical engineering):

You get an array `unsigned char buffer[128];` used to read data from a source byte by byte, containing data of the structure:

```
struct Pixel {

unsigned char x;
unsigned char y;
unsigned char greyValue;

};
```

The task is: Create an instance of a pixel and copy the data content from the header of the buffer using "memcpy".

My aproach does not seem to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Pixel {
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char y;
    unsigned char greyValue;
};

int main() 
{
    unsigned char buffer[128] = {2,4,44};

    struct Pixel singlePixel;

    memcpy(singlePixel, buffer, 3);

    printf("singlePixel.x = %d\n", singlePixel.x);
    printf("singlePixel.y = %d\n", singlePixel.y);
    printf("singlePixel.greyValue = %d\n", singlePixel.greyValue);


    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that singlePixel.x = 2, singlePixel.y = 4 and singlePixel.greyValue = 44.

When debugging I get the error: `incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘memcpy’`

I'm also not at all sure if my approach is up to the task, since I don't understand exactly how this should works with the buffer...

Comment: In this call memcpy(singlePixel, buffer, 3); the first parameter does not have a pointer type

Comment: Your immediate error can be solved by `memcpy(&singlePixel, buffer, 3);`, but in general you are making an assumption here that the memory layout of the structure is the same as of the array, that I am not sure can be guaranteed..